Tomcat LifecycleListener multithreads problem
A LifecycleListener's initial variable loses it's value when it is called by lifecycleEvent method.
I have a listener which implements LifecycleListener and the constructor initiate a private variable.
However when the lifecycleEvent method is called, the value is null.
The test logs showed that the constructor was called by the thread named "main" but the lifecycleEvent method was called by the thread named "Catalina-utility-1".
It was fixed by moving the variable to an enum and initialize it in the lister constructor.
Does any one know how it works?
Why the thread "Catalina-utility-1" never called instantiate the listener?
CustomizedListener.java
public class CustomizedListener implements LifecycleListener {
    private volatile SomeObject var;

    public CustomizedListener() {
        // Initialize the variable var
        this.SomeObject = new SomeObject(0);
        System.out.println("(Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ") Instantiating CustomizedListener with the initial value of var: " + var.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) {
        if (lifecycleEvent.getType().equals("periodic")) {
            if (!(lifecycleEvent.getSource() instanceof Server server)) {
                return;
            }
            String varValue = var == null ? "null" : var.getValue();
            System.out.println("(Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ") Method lifecycleEvent is called. The value of var is: " + varValue);
        }
    }
}

TomcatStarter.java
public class TomcatStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Skip other tomcat setup steps
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.getServer().addLifecycleListener(new CustomizedListener());
        tomcat.init();
        tomcat.start();
    }
}

Logs
(Thread name: main) Instantiating CustomizedListener with the initial value of var: 0
(Thread name: Catalina-utility-1) Method lifecycleEvent is called. The value of var is: null
(Thread name: Catalina-utility-1) Method lifecycleEvent is called. The value of var is: null
(Thread name: Catalina-utility-1) Method lifecycleEvent is called. The value of var is: null
...

